# What is the best Pig plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor, apache-pig

I'm about to start playing around with PIG-latin, and I was hoping to get some text highlighting and such for it in Eclipse. Doing a quick Google search, I saw a couple of Eclipse plugins for it. Are they all still in development? Which is the best?

Comment: If you're going to downvote and vote to close, you could at least mention why. There are lots of questions like this for other languages on StackOverflow, so why mine in particular deserves downvoting is a mystery to me.

Comment: I think this is a fine question. I'd like to hear if there are more alternatives to PigPen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are a list of Pig related tools: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/PigTools, there are several eclipse plugin.

Comment: Yup, I found that yesterday, but forgot to mention it here. I tried out the three available plugins for Eclipse there, and liked PigEditor best for my simple purposes. It's way easier to install than PigPen, and it gives all the basic highlighting and coloring features I wanted.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/pig-eclipse listed there is very lightweight, and has all you need.

Answer (score 5):

I have taken over the maintenance and development of [the "lightweight" Pig Eclipse plug in](https://github.com/eyala/pig-eclipse) described above.

In the latest release, it provides syntax highlighting, auto complete, "javadoc" style tooltips, and open declaration (F3) support for Pig 0.11 - 0.14 (you can choose in the preferences).

Here's [the update site.](http://github.com/eyala/pig-eclipse-update-site/raw/master) (the update site moved from Google Code to GitHub, so you may need to add it manually if you have a pre-existing installation)

Contributions, comments and improvements are welcome!

Comment: As of 2015-07-28 the update site link is not working!

Comment: Nvm, since the update site when added to Eclipse is working fine. Thanks for the nice work.

Answer (score 3):

I am working on [PigEditor](http://romainr.github.com/PigEditor/) and try to keep it simple while providing Java Eclipse's like functionalities:

- syntax/errors highlighting
- check alias name existence
- auto complete keywords, UDF names
- outline...

I am using it daily and update it regularly when I start using new Pig features.

Comment: the syntax coloring is great, but the Xtext nature is super annoying, everything appear as problems, and if I disable it it keeps asking me if I want to enable Xtext :(

Answer (score 2):

[Hue](http://gethue.com) now comes with a Pig editor supporting syntax highlighting, autocomplete, one click to execute, saving scripts... It also integrate with the other apps like Job Browser and Hive Metastore UI.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [PigPen](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/PigPen)? I think it is still technically in development, but it appears to be pretty mature.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple syntax highlighter for IntelliJ:

https://twitter.com/rjurney/status/201052603365343232